# FullCalendar.io Scheduler - Can I have resources as columns and days of week (or dates) as rows?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

In Fullcalendar Scheduler's TimeGrid View with vertical resource view (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view), is it possible to create a custom view (or modify existing view) to have resources as columns without the dates underneath and rather have the rows as dates or days of week.

Here's a snapshot of what I would like.

[image]

Comment: It's possible to create custom views yes, which might be made easier by copying existing view templates and then changing it, but I would say it's probably not a very simple task. And then you have to maintain it as well if you want to be compatible with future versions of fullCalendar. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js has some details. Your suggested view is more or less a 90-degree flip of the Timeline view, so that might be a starting point. Or consider whether you can get away with just using the timeline view - it's the same thing just a different way round.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply! Initially, that was my first idea, and I successfully had the Timeline View with resources in the left side, which, for me, worked great. However, the customer really wants to have it the other way, so I'm trying to see if it's feasible to accommodate his request, though I know it would be simpler to just have it in Timeline view.

Comment: Do you have some hint as to where I can get those view templates in the code?

Comment: Just take them from the fullCalendar source code on GitHub. It's open source. Make sure you comply with any license conditions. The scheduler product, which includes the timeline view, is not always free in all circumstances so maybe check what you can do with that code

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have a look at their source code and see what I can do with it to try customizing a view.

Comment: P.s. you might want to prepare your client for the possibility that this whim over layout isn't going to be cheap...

Comment: That's a good point! In fact, I checked other libraries that do this kind of calendar, and they ain't cheap. $500, $1000+, ... https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/, https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/licenses.shtml

Comment: Indeed. The cost of your time to develop and maintain a custom view won't be small, is my prediction. So the client has to decide on bearing the extra cost vs. using an existing view which is almost the same as what they want. I'm sure they'd soon get used to it

Comment: I also need to implement something like this. A few years passed by since this question was asked, are there any prebuilt solution which appeared recently?